# Can I make my Mac sleep on a schedule automatically?

Tags: macos, sleep, macbook, automation, macbook-pro

I'd like my Mac to sleep at 7PM every day automatically. The reason that the schedule that comes with the computer for setting up a consistent time for the computer to sleep doesn't work is that it's very easy to not have the computer sleep.

It presents a ten minute warning and all the user has to do in order to skip the sleep is to click cancel.

I'd like a setup that sleeps the computer at 7pm daily, ideally without an option of skipping it.

Comment: I presume this is a social issue? Even if you can force the sleep at 7, won't the user just be able to wake it at 7.01?

Comment: Great point. I think it's more about forcing a break-point in usage. They can't use it at 7.01 because there is a screen time limit that blocks apps after 7p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'd like a setup that sleeps the computer at 7pm daily

**Option 1:**

You can include the following command in a scheduled script:

```
pmset sleepnow
```

> To try this yourself, launch Terminal and use one of the following
> commands. Remember there is no warning, sleep is immediate.
>
> ```
> pmset sleepnow
> ```
>
> Hit return and the Mac is instantly put to sleep.
>
> That is one of the most simple uses of pmset, which is a full featured
> power management utility.

**Option 2:**

Use AppleScript since AppleScript can be scheduled easily:

> The syntax for the AppleScript sleep method is as follows:
>
> ```
> osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
> ```
>
> `osascript` is a command line tool that runs OSA scripts, the `-e`
> flag executes the script in quotes rather than looking for a file, and
> the text in quotations is basic AppleScript.

Source: [Sleep a Mac from the Command Line](https://osxdaily.com/2012/07/22/sleep-a-mac-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: Awesome! Can you please include instructions for scheduling the apple script?

Comment: @Cauder [macos - Scheduling a terminal command or script file to run daily at a specific time Mac OS X - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854193/scheduling-a-terminal-command-or-script-file-to-run-daily-at-a-specific-time-mac)

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to the computer to lock and go to the lock screen. I tried this code` tell application "Finder" to sleep
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "q" using {control down, command down}` but I don't think it's able to do the keystroke after finder sleeps